# R - Sparse Matrix - Print First Column

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am having some trouble printing the first column of my sparse matrix. here is a snapshot of the matrix

```
           RESOURCE17183 RESOURCE39353 MGR_ID85475
1             .             1           1
2             1             .           .
```

I try to print it by using the the command

```
print(x_train[,1])
```

However I get some weird output

```
1 2 
1 0
```

The output I was expecting was something like

```
      RESOURCE17183
1     .
2     1
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Try `print(x_train[,1,drop=FALSE])` - this is not a sparse matrix issue specifically. Check out the help file and the `drop=` argument here - `?"["`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That will help us provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @thelatemail The dropping was not surprising to me, the change from `("1"=.,"2"=1)` to `c("1"=1,"2"=0)` was odd. Maybe the output was just "representative" and not what was actually observed which I would have expected to be `c("1"=0,"2"=1)`.